# I want generate a crystal report with multiple Sub details involve multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, linq-to-dataset

[image: i want similar to this picture i created]

i display data in grid like this and want a crystal report like this print the data.

but i have no clue how to do this. Let me try to explain further this case.
for every row of main table i have displayed subdetails in subgridvew and this subgrid data is fetched by keys in main table and an other table (this table has fixed values).
this would be first report i would create.
please gimme clue or tell if  i am not so clear about asking question

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of requirement you need to use cross tab...where in rows you need to provide data from table 1 and for rows first take data from table then from table 2 which will geoup as per your requirement

Comment: thank you for guidence i am gonna check what cross tab report is.

Comment: its not the saperate report... its a functionality in crystal reports.. add a crosstab and do as suggested

Comment: i dont think its a cross tab report. i think there is sub reports in row for main table,And my problem in to link subreports table with two parameter one from main table and other from another table

Comment: i had to add sub reports for details ,acessry and xtable